# htaccess rewrite rule, parameter with unicode letters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, unicode

I have tried to follow many answer in the site, without success.
I am trying to rewrite:

```
domain.com/articles/<author>
```

To:

```
domain.com/articles/index.php?author=<author>
```

My current rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w*)$ /articles/index.php?author=$1 [B]
```

That works with letters or numbers, but not with unicode charachters like **א** and **"**.

For **א**, i am getting the following error:

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>
> localhost Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.9

And for **"**:

> Access forbidden!
>
> You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either
>   read-protected or not readable by the server.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 403
>
> localhost Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.9

And i need them both.

**EDIT:**

After reading @user82217 comment i have tried again (.*) regex, this time with the END flag like this:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /articles/index.php?author=$1 [END]
```

Now **א** case is being interpreted well. But **"** case still gives the same error (Access Forbidden).

@user82217 has suggested to investigate the log. For the **"** case the log is:

> Cannot map GET /articles/%22 HTTP/1.1 to file

**Conclusion:**

As @user82217 said in a comment, It appears that under Windows OS an address with **"** char is considered an illegal file to serve, although the address isn't a file at all.
So i gave up the **"** case for now. Will glad to hear if there is a way to get around that.

Comment: Do you need to be so specific, can you just match _everything_ ie. `(.*)`?

Comment: @user82217: I have tried. Then i get: "Internal Server Error".

Comment: just tested this scenario. It does work, but only in virtual host non-directory context. Place your rule inside the `<VirtualHost>` and you'll get all those unicode and double quotes.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/articles/(?!index\.php)(.*)$ /articles/index.php?author=$1 [END]`

Comment: @Deadooshka Is that can be done with only .htaccess file?

Comment: how can it reach a htaccess with unsuccessful file system mapping?

Comment: @Deadooshka. I am posting an answer with your solution (not about adding it to <VirtualHost> but adding it to the global config context).
Can you write an answer based on my new answer and then i will delete mine and mark yours as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(\w*)$ /articles/index.php?author=$1 [B]
> ```

If you simply replace your pattern with `(.*)` then you will get a rewrite-loop (which is your 500 Internal Server Error). You could either make the `RewriteRule` *pattern* match everything *except slashes*:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /articles/index.php?author=$1 [B,L]
```

However, from your examples it's not clear where your `.htaccess` file is located. The above assumes it is in the `/articles` subdirectory.

Alternatively, you could check the query string and only process the directive if the query string is empty:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) /articles/index.php?author=$1 [B,L]
```

> But " case still gives the same error (Access Forbidden).

**UPDATE:** Ah, this is probably a more fundamental error and is probably a limitation of the OS (are you using Windows?). The `"` character is not a valid filename character. Apache is unable to map this to a valid filename which would appear to result in a system generated 403 Forbidden.

Comment: Thanks! [but:] (1) The .htaccess file is located in /articles directory. (2) Your first option is causing "Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request" in all cases: letters/numbers/א/"
(3) Your second options causes: "Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server..." (4) Adding the B flag i have omitted is giving "Server error!
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script."

Comment: In order to find the details of the error you need to check your error log.

Comment: Your first option's (RewriteRule ([^/]*) /articles/index.php?author=$1 [B,L]) log was "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error"

Comment: (RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) /articles/index.php?author=$1 [B,L]) which caused "Object not found!" doesn't produce a record in the log.

Comment: Also thanks for the log advice, i am adding the log about the " case as an edit to my question.

Comment: Ah, the rewrite loop... I think the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ needs anchors. ie. it should be `^([^/]*)$`, not simply `([^/]*)`. However, the problem with `"` is more fundamental - I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the double quotes issue:
The **"** character is not a valid filename character like @MrWhite said.

@Deadooshka stated in his comment that it cannot be done in .htaccess context.
I think he is right.

@Deadooshka also said it can be done in the <]VirtualHost[> context. However, in my development server i don't use <]VirtualHost[> context.

So the solution was to put the rewrite rule under the global context of Apache's config file (in my case: C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf) like this:

```
# <<< existing line >>>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
# <<< existing line >>>
# <<< solution >>>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /articles/(\w*)$ /articles/index.php?author=$1 [B]
# <<< solution >>>
```